# How many permutations of a string don't start or end with $-1$

Tags: combinatorics

If you have a string composed of $1$'s, $0$'s and $-1$'s, how many permutations of this string don't start or end with $-1$ and also don't have their second-to-last position equal to $-1$?

So if we have $a$ $1$'s, $b$ $0$'s, and $c$ $-1$'s, then we know the total number of permutations would be:

$T = \frac{(a+b+c)!}{a!\cdot b!\cdot c!}$

Now we just need to subtract off the permutations that violate the constraint, but I'm unsure how to do that.

Comment: Please share your efforts. On this site it is expected that you share your efforts so that the community can help you

Comment: @Shailesh I've added slightly more, but I'm still unsure how to make the next step. Also, this is not a homework problem, so I'm honestly just looking for a generalized solution.

Answer (score 1):

- $P$ collection of strings not starting with $-1$
- $Q$ collection of strings not ending with $-1$
- $R$ collection of strings with no $-1$ on second to last position.

If I understand well then you are looking for: $|(P\cup Q)\cap R|$.

Apply:$$|(P\cup Q)\cap R|=|(P\cap R)\cup (Q\cap R)|=|P\cap R|+|Q\cap R|-|P\cap Q\cap R|$$

Answer (score 0):

There are three positions where you cannot have $-1$, so what can be put there? There are only a few cases, and in each case you can easily find the number of ways to fill in the remaining numbers. To make it even faster, you can notice that you first want to arrange the negative and non-negative numbers, and then later you can decide which non-negative numbers are $0$ and which are $1$. That makes it even easier because at the start you are forced to put non-negative at those three positions.

Comment: Can you write an equation? I understand what I need to do conceptually.

Comment: @Jane: Well *true blue anil* has given you a full answer. The problem is that you've nothing left to try.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find it easier to compute directly.

There are $(a+b+c-3)$ places where $c's$ can be put, and then permute the rest, thus

$\dbinom{a+b+c-3}{c}\dfrac{(a+b)!}{a!b!}$

Comment: You're welcome !